# From Jenkins job, getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: Am able to run through same project in eclipse

Tags: java, jenkins

I'm getting the following error in Jenkins' job:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: testcases\Scenarios.xls 
  (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Though the following code executes without any error in Eclipse:

```java
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Path/sample.xls");
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Where are you getting this error? Have you cloned the repository in jenkins using scm and tried checking again if the file exists in the said path? This cannot be a Jenkins problem if you encounter problem in compilation but rather a classpath problem.

Comment: As i said getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: when i run the project through Jenkins.Same project am able to run through Eclipse without any error

Answer (score 0):

If you have sample.xls in test/resources, use the following code. If in a different place under src directory, please modify.
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/resources/sample.xls");